# Cannot Start Compiler: The SDK is not specified in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, intellij-15

I get the error when clicking on the run button that says cannot compiler and I set it to JDK 1.8 in the SDK part but still get the same error in IntelliJ Ultimate. Any thought how this can be fixed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the project include SDKs for other languages etc.? Android, C/++.
Those will need defining too.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check also the `Project` tab on that page, and each module's SDK under the `Modules` tab and its `Dependencies` sub-tab. They all allow you to specify what SDK to use at different levels. The `Project` tab should be set to the only SDK you have, but it might not have anything set and similarly for the module dependencies - they should be set to 'use Project SDK' but they might not be. That's usually the source of the kind of error you're seeing.

Comment: On Android Studio it's possible that the SDK may not be completely or properly installed.  Setting the SDK's to an older version worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do check if the sdk path is set under platform settings-->SDKs. Some times the sdk is not set there.